# How to compile a C/C++ program with extra code caves?

Tags: compilation

I'd like to do some tests with code caves. Given a C or C++ program, how can I make the compiler (gcc, clang, etc) insert extra code caves in the binary?

(I don't want to add backdoors directly into my code, but to insert code after compilation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boils down to having a block of virtual memory that is a) readable+executable and b) writeable at the stage where you want to place any payloads. The second constraint dictates where and how you create such spaces based on your needs.

### Stack-allocated

If you just want a place to dump a little bit of shellcode to be run when a process, you can simply stack-allocate an array:

```
void my_vulnerable_function() {
    char foo[32];
    gets(foo);
}
```

To make this feasible, make sure to compile with `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack` flags passed to GCC. You might also want to turn off ASLR so your stack is in a predictable location. I've honestly never tried to use clang to make a program insecure on purpose, so I don't know what flags you'd use in that case.

### Memory mapped region

If you want to make something more long-lived, but in-memory, you can `mmap` a region with rwx access:

```
mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Now just write some code into it, and jump into it when you're ready.

### Executable file placeholder

If you want a placeholder in the executable file which is executable and can be edited with a hex editor, just make sure your compiler emits a reference to a string literal, which :

```
int main() { 
    char* copyright = "Copyright 2019 John Zhau. All rights reserved.";
    puts(copyright);
}
```

You can then patch the contents of that string in the ELF file itself. Your program will need to jump to an address in the string (respecting any relocation performed by ASLR/ELF loading). Here's a simple way to do this:

```
int main() { 
    char* copyright = "Copyright 2019 John Zhau. All rights reserved.";
    void (*foo)(void ) = ((void (*)(void)) copyright);
    foo();
    // or, more succinctly,
    (*(void(*)()) copyright)(); 
}
```

This casts a pointer to the first character of the string, as a pointer to a function. Invoking that "function" through that pointer will cause execution to jump to your buffer--hopefully by that time it will have valid shellcode.

Comment: It seems the fastest and easiest way would be to allocate a ```null``` array. Would just doing ```char cave[1000] = NULL;```, along with ```chmod``` and ```chown``` (instead of ```mmap```) allow me to execute my injected shellcode?

Comment: @JohnZhau You can't `chmod` a segment of virtual memory.  My hunch is that `char cave[1000] = NULL` is going to end up in .bss, which may not be executable on your system. By using a string literal, you're much more likely to cause the symbol and memory to be emitted in the known-to-be-executable .text region. You also don't need `mmap` in that case; `mmap` is strictly for the situation where you want to dynamically create such a cave at runtime.

Comment: @JohnZhau Furthermore, the string approach I outlined isn't actually noticeably slower. I tried my own example and it was plenty fast to compile, reasonably fast to patch by hand, and reliable to execute afterwards.